# How do I write conditional code based on which router link is active

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-router

My attempt is like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs search-selector" role="tablist">
  <li routerLinkActive="active"
    [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }">
    <a routerLink="{{ myroute[0].link }}">{{ myroute[0].label }}</a>
  </li>
  <li routerLinkActive="active"
    [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }">
    <a routerLink="{{ myroute[1].link }}">{{ myroute[1].label }}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div *ngif="route0 is active">do something related to route 0</div>
<div *ngif="route1 is active">do something related to route 1</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own structural directive, similar to `NgIf`, where you will pass route and render something in DOM if your active route matches the one you passed to directive, something like this:

**if-route.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Directive({ selector: '[ifRoute]' })
export class IfRouteDirective {

  private hasView = false;
  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    private router: Router) { }

  @Input() set ifRoute(route: string) {
    this.performCheck(route);

    this.subscription = this.router.events.subscribe(
      res => {
        this.performCheck(route);
      }
    )
  }

  performCheck(route) {
    if (route === this.router.url && !this.hasView) {
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
      this.hasView = true;
    } else if (route !== this.router.url && this.hasView) {
      this.viewContainer.clear();
      this.hasView = false;
    };
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

You would use it like this in your template:

```
<p *ifRoute="'/login'">
  This will be displayed only if you are on login route.
</p>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. If I hit the exact route in browser it renders but doesn't go away once I navigate to other routes. and if I start with other route and navigate to it , doesn't render at all. check it out https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dyatjo

Comment: ifRoute() seems to be loaded only when a user types url and not when some link is clicked.

Comment: @ishandutta2007 Check out my edited answer. You have to subscribe to route changes in order to check condition on each route change. Note that I'm unsubscribing in `ngOnDestroy` lifecycle hook in order to prevent memory leaks. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Now the opposite thing is happening, if you hit the target route directly from browser it doesnt trigger but if you navigate from other parts of app it does. Did you check the stackblitz I pasted above ?

Comment: @ishandutta2007 Check out updated answer, to cover this use case as well it is required to perform a check before subscribing. I'll refactor this code in a few minutes, but this is now working as intended. Edit: code refactored.

Answer (score 0):

@stefan-svrkota's answer is great but I found `*ngIf="router.url=='/login'"` also works